# How can I display a free floating panel for an input form using PopupControlExtender?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popupcontrolextender

I'm currently playing around with the PopupControlExtender in the ajaxToolkit and can't quite get the functionality I want.

I'm trying to display a free floating "help" panel for an input form.

Once the user presses the help button on the form the panel pops up and displays no problem however once I click back on the main form it dissappears again.

I understand this good behaviour for most applications but I'd like to get the popped up panel to stay on screen until explictly closed (via a close button within the panel itself).

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Might give the ModalPopupExtender a try.  It locks the main page out until an event takes place on the popup.